# How to use multiple document.cookie in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Multiple `document.cookie` is not working for me.

My code:

```
var objFecha = new Date();
objFecha.setTime(objFecha.getTime() + (86400 * 1000));
var strExpiracion = objFecha.toGMTString();
document.cookie = 'MyCookie;expires=' + strExpiracion;
```

This code works me, but the other does not:

```
var objFecha = new Date();
objFecha.setTime(objFecha.getTime() + (86400 * 1000));
var strExpiracion = objFecha.toGMTString();
document.cookie = 'MyCookie;expires=' + strExpiracion;

var objFecha2 = new Date();
objFecha2.setTime(objFecha2.getTime() + (30 * 1000));
var strExpiracion2 = objFecha2.toGMTString();
document.cookie = 'MyCookie2;expires=' + strExpiracion2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you actually create 2 cookies but with the same name (empty name), so this cookie always has "MyCookie2" as the value.

You need to add a `=` operator when setting it (even for empty values), like this:

```
document.cookie = 'MyCookie=;expires=' + str;
```